# How can I get the logged-in user's username using JDBCRealm?

Tags: java, jsf, authentication, managed-bean, j-security-check

I'm running Glassfish 3.0 and I'm implementing JDBCRealm for login authentication. The username and roles are saved in a table called usertable. The authentication is working as expected.

But the problem is now when the user logs in, how can I retrieve the username of the logged in user in the application?

PS: I'm implementing JSF page and Managed Bean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JSF, you can retrieve the current Principal associated with the request and hence, the current session, using the [`ExternalContext`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) object, which can be retrieved from the [`FacesContext`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getExternalContext%28%29). The Principal associated with the request is accessible from the ExternalContext using the [`getUserPrincipal()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) method:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
```

The above invocation can be done in a JSF managed bean. You can invoke the `getName()` method on the Principal object to retrieve the name of the user as a String.

Note that, it possible for you to obtain a `Principal` instance that references the Anonymous user, if you are retrieving the Principal before authentication, or if the authentication scheme does not protect the entire site.

Comment: `FacesContext.getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();`? Shouldn't it be like `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();`? Did that exist in some older versions of JSF at the time of this post?

Comment: @Tiny, yes the `getCurrentInstance()` static method must be invoked first if you dont have the FacesContext instance.

Answer (score 3):

[Request.getRemoteUser](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29) or [Request.getUserPrincipal](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29), independent of the realm you use for authentication, so if you use a File realm for testing and a JDBC realm for production it will work in both cases.  By the way, if you use JDBCRealm also have a look at [FlexibleJDBCRealm](http://flexiblejdbcrealm.wamblee.org/site/).

Comment: Does that FlexibleJDBCRealm exist in some version(s) of GlassFish now?  It is mentioned at the end of that linked page, "*I have been in contact with SUN in the hope that FlexibleJdbcRealm (or something with similar flexibility) will be added to a future version of glassfish.*"

Comment: @tiny Not that I'm aware of.  But [the last message on the mailing list](http://wamblee.org/pipermail/flexiblejdbcrealm/2013-September/000056.html) says that the current version also works on GF4.

Answer (score 2):

Your authenticate method should return a java.security.Principal which will contain the name.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html